# How to centering abstract and lines above and below the abstract

Tags: abstract

I want to do the following:

1. I need one line above the abstract and other line below the abstract. The width  of lines should be equal to the width of abstract. The lines should
   not be larger than the width of the abstract.
2. In the output pdf file, I am getting the word "Abstract" at the
   center of 1st line of the abstract section. I need that it start like as "`Abstract. Each chapter should be preceded by an abstract .......`", which Abstract and the text of abstract are in the same 1st    line of abstract with no-indent.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abstract,lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.25in, paperheight=9.5in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\title{Contribution Title}
\author{Name of First Author and Name of Second Author}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
Each chapter should be preceded by an abstract (10--15 lines long) that summarizes the content. The abstract will appear  and be available with unrestricted access. This allows unregistered users to read the abstract as a teaser for the complete chapter. As a general rule the abstracts will not appear in the printed version of your book unless it is the style of your particular book or that of the series to which your book belongs.
\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\end{abstract}
\section{introduction}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{abstract}\end{abstract}`.

Comment: @ Sigur problem 1-4 is still troublesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redefine the environment  `abstract` in this way:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abstract,lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.25in, paperheight=9.5in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\title{Contribution Title}
\author{Name of First Author and Name of Second Author}
\maketitle

\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\begin{quote}
\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\par{\bfseries \abstractname.}}
{\medskip\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}
\end{quote}
}


\begin{abstract}
Each chapter should be preceded by an abstract (10--15 lines long) that summarizes the content. The abstract will appear  and be available with unrestricted access. This allows unregistered users to read the abstract as a teaser for the complete chapter. As a general rule the abstracts will not appear in the printed version of your book unless it is the style of your particular book or that of the series to which your book belongs.
\end{abstract}

\section{introduction}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```