# How to adjust width of abstract and add lines above and below it

Tags: indentation, abstract

I am trying to create an abstract like below:

[image]

How can an abstract be moved to the right and have lines placed above it? Also is it possible to align the 'keywords'.

For the first there is an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151583/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-abstract) and the second there are answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436603/lines-above-and-below-the-abstract) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219258/how-to-centering-abstract-and-lines-above-and-below-the-abstract). How can I combine these to get both please?

This is the text so far

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
% move abstract in a bit
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151583/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-abstract
\renewenvironment{abstract}
 {\small
  \list{}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.25\linewidth}% <---------- CHANGE HERE
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
  }%
  \item\relax }
 {\endlist} 
\title{ The title}
\author{} \date{}
\begin{document}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28109/how-can-i-place-a-one-column-abstract-in-a-two-column-document
\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      {\lipsum[1] \lipsum[2]}
    \end{abstract}
    \hspace{0.245\linewidth} \small keywords : {\lipsum[2]} \vspace{1cm}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\section{Intro} 
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Which produces a correctly moved abstract but unaligned 'keywords'. I have been unable to also add the lines. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One quick hack is to use a `tabular` environment. This involves hard coding the width of the table so that it wraps the text and using `flushright` to move it to the right handside margin. Using just this does not line up perfectly with the right margin of the text body due to the cell border in the table but you can use `@{} p{12cm} @{}` to remove this (thanks Werner)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}

\title{ The title} \author{} \date{}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[{%
  \small
  \begin{flushright}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{0.75\linewidth} @{}}
      \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
      \lipsum[1]  \\ [-5pt]
      \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
      keywords: \lipsum[2] \vspace{1cm}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{flushright}
}]

\section{Intro}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

Comment: Just use this column spec: `@{} p{12cm} @{}`